# Constructible sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Is it possible to write down all the constructible sets in $\mathbf{C}$ (endowed with the Zariski topology) or some other "simple" space?

Comment: What do you mean write down *all* of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, for each complex number $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $\{z\}$ is a constructible set. So if you're going to write down all the constructible subsets, you at least need to be able to write down all the complex numbers. Depending on what you mean by "write down", this might not be possible...

But the constructible sets in $\mathbb{C}$ do enjoy a simple description: they are exactly the finite and cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ (which is to say that $(\mathbb{C},+,\cdot,0,1)$ is a [strongly minimal structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_minimal_theory)). This is a consequence of the fact that any polynomial in one variable has finitely many roots.

So you can describe all constructible subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ as:
$$\{X\subseteq \mathbb{C}\mid X\text{ is finite or }\mathbb{C}\setminus X\text{ is finite}\}$$

Comment: Under certain laws of physics (not ours, though), immortality and superspeed one can easily write down all the complex numbers!

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I should have said that I am interested in a "classification" or more explicit description of the constructible subsets of $\mathbf{C}$ (which is what I meant by "writing them all down", of course this was not meant literally). A professor of mine would have said instead "we're gonna hunt them down, every one of them" lol